# I just installed hexo static site generator on Debian and ran hexo server to see but it gave a TypeError

Tags: node.js, hexo, static-site-generation

I am not sure if I did anything wrong. This is all I did,
I followed the documentation to do the installation.
I had git and nodejs preinstalled, to install hexo cli I ran this,
`sudo npm install -g hexo-cli`
Then I checked if hexo is installed by running `hexo -v` and it showed version and everything, this is what it showed.

```
hexo-cli: 4.2.0
os: Linux 4.19.0-14-amd64 linux x64
http_parser: 2.9.4
node: 10.24.0
v8: 6.8.275.32-node.59
uv: 1.24.1
zlib: 1.2.11
brotli: 1.0.7
ares: 1.14.0
modules: 64
nghttp2: 1.41.0
napi: 7
openssl: 1.1.1d
icu: 63.1
unicode: 11.0
cldr: 34.0
tz: 2018e
```

Then went ahead and created a new folder called hexosite with this command,
`hexo init hexosite` it created the folder and everything. So to see if everything worked I ran
`hexo server`. And came up with this error, I didn't change anything anywhere. This is the error message.

```
INFO  Validating config
INFO  Start processing
FATAL { err:
   TypeError: line.matchAll is not a function
       at res.value.res.value.split.map.line (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/hexo-util/lib/highlight.js:128:26)
       at Array.map (<anonymous>)
       at closeTags (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/hexo-util/lib/highlight.js:126:37)
       at highlight (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/hexo-util/lib/highlight.js:119:10)
       at highlightUtil (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/hexo-util/lib/highlight.js:23:16)
       at data.content.dataContent.replace (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/hexo/lib/plugins/filter/before_post_render/backtick_code_block.js:92:17)
       at String.replace (<anonymous>)
       at Hexo.backtickCodeBlock (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/hexo/lib/plugins/filter/before_post_render/backtick_code_block.js:19:30)
       at Hexo.tryCatcher (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
       at Hexo.<anonymous> (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:15:34)
       at Promise.each.filter (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/hexo/lib/extend/filter.js:67:52)
       at tryCatcher (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
       at Object.gotValue (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:166:18)
       at Object.gotAccum (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:155:25)
       at Object.tryCatcher (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
       at Promise._settlePromise (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
       at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:641:10)
       at _drainQueueStep (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:97:12)
       at _drainQueue (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
       at Async._drainQueues (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/seek/Data/hexosite/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14) } 'Something\'s wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: %s' '\u001b[4mhttps://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html\u001b[24m'
```

I have no experience with hexo, this is the first time I decided to play with it. I read their documentation on troubleshooting, but didn't find anything about this.

If you know anything about this please feel free to answer, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

Function `String.matchAll()` is supported in Node.js from version `12.0.0`, so, upgrade your nodejs to a version greater than `12.0.0`.

OR

Changing the value of config item `highlight->enable` in file `_config.xml` from `true` to `false`, this can avoid the exception.

```
highlight:
  enable: false
```

But, this will turn off code highlighting.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for now, but I decided to switch to jekyll. But I will keep this question like this for now, and if more people had the same issue, may be this will become active again then I will choose the most helpful answer.